# Change language from my application in iphone

Tags: iphone

How i can change my language within my app ،knowing that my application include xib and also NSlocalizedstring inside my nib.

Comment: The user can change the language in the settings screen. Don't allow the user to change it from within your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For localization on iPhone, you must add specific `.strings` files to your project for each language you want to support.
Here is a great [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial) about localization for iPhone.

Comment: Ok i know but how i can refresh my application which include tab bar controller after i change to my language , i want to empathize that change language not from iPhone  settings  it is within (inside) my app